# When using a virtual base class in a multiple inheritance scenario, is it necessary for all derived classes to reference the virtual base?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

The US Air Force's JSF C++ coding standard requires that the virtual base class be declared for each derived class that accesses the virtual base.

For example, in the following hierarchy:

```
  A
 / \
B1  B2
C1  C2
 \ /
  D
```

... the rule they impose in this standard (AV Rule 88.1, for reference), requires the classes to be declared like so:

```
class A;
class B1 : virtual A;
class B2 : virtual A;
class C1 : B1, virtual A;
class C2 : B2, virtual A;
class D  : C1, C2, virtual A;
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this semantically different from only inheriting virtually in the declaration @ B1/B2, and not specifying `virtual A` at each subsequent class declaration?
2. If it's semantically different, why would anyone /want/ to leave it off?  It seems silly to me that you'd absolutely have to do this at each layer of inheritance since that adds a potential point of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It semantically identical, since each derived class will have exactly *one* virtual base of type `A`. Mentio­ning the virtual base explicitly is quite nice, because the most-derived class constructs the virtual base (unlike what happens for non-virtual bases), and the construction order is important to keep in mind when writing the constructors of the derived classes.

I don't have a technical answer for (2). You don't have to do it, but it would be nice if you did. Like calling your parents, I suppose. As with many things, C++ doesn't force you to be reasonable.

Comment: I wish I could give another +1 for the laugh.  But in all seriousness, I would like one small clarification.  Why would you care whether the most derived type constructs the virtual base?  Would you still potentially end up with two `A`s?

Comment: @BrianVandenberg: No, but you have to be careful with the initialization order, and you have to remember that only the most-derived class constructs the (unique) virtual base. Think about how the intermediate classes feel about that. A non-trivial example would take a bit of code to spell out, but then again, virtual inheritance is a very arcane language feature to begin with... but try and work it out for yourself and see how the order matters.